# Async Task await

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, async-await

I am trying to understand async method in c#
I have created a wcf service that delay 10 seconds. I am calling the wcf service from a console application the value **asyncValue** is never sets. It just closes the console app.

Why is the **asyncValue** never set to Ok?

Wcf Service

```
[ServiceContract]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class AsyncService 
{
    [OperationContract]
    public async Task<string> TimeAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return "Ok";
    }
}
```

Console application

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<string> asyncValue = GetAsyncTimeFromWcf();           
}

private static async Task<string> GetAsyncTimeFromWcf()
{
    AsyncService.AsyncServiceClient client = new AsyncService.AsyncServiceClient();
    Task<string> asyncTime = client.TimeAsync();

    return await asyncTime;
}
```

Comment: @L.B You cannot `await asyncValue` inside the `main` method because is not marked as `async` and you cannot mark the main as async.

Comment: @user3046164: You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [`async` console app](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html) blog posts useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `await` keyword to make sense you need to do something with the return value. The purpose of the `async`/`await` feature is to allow the application to continue with other, non-related, code until you need to use the result of the awaited task.

In your case, you call `await` but you don't *use* the return value, so the `Main` method continues and effectively exists the application. For example, try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task<string> asyncValue = GetAsyncTimeFromWcf();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for server...");
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result = {0}", asyncValue.Result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

You should find the console will output `Waiting for server...` for 10 seconds then once the server returns it will display `Ok`.

Comment: I understand now. I had to create an example to learn and understand, but I got stuck. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` method ends before the WCF call returns.

To see the result, you can add the line:

```
  Console.WriteLine(asyncValue.Result);
```

The call to [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), will [`Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the task to complete, and then get the result.

Answer (score 1):

`asyncValue` is a Task whose `Result` will contain the final value when it finishes. You have to wait for this result either by calling `asyncValue.Result` or by calling `asyncValue.Wait()` and then check `asyncValue.Result`.

You can't use `await asyncValue` or `await GetAsyncTimeFromWcf()` in the `Main` method of a Console program, because you can't mark it as `async`.

Just try:

```
Task<string> asyncValue = GetAsyncTimeFromWcf(); 
var time=asyncValue.Result;
Console.WriteLine(time);
```